# R - Select Rows Where Number of Values Satisfies Condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `df`, what I want to do is select all rows where there are at least `n` values in that row satisfying some condition `c`.

For example, I want rows from `df` such that at least 50% of the values (or columns) in the row are greater than 0.75.

Here is what I came up with to accomplish this:

```
test <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) (length(x[x > 0.75]) / length(x) > 0.5)]
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, apply(df,  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I am very new to R, so I'm pretty stuck at this point, what's the problem here?

Comment: "at least n values in that row" Can we interpret this as "at least n columns in that row"?

Comment: Yes I believe so, I'll add that in

Comment: I think you should consider using a matrix if your data is like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantages/disadvantages to using a matrix would be? I trust you are likely correct though, I kept it in a dataframe since that's how I read the data in initially.

Comment: Most operations you'll end up doing with data like this are faster and clearer with a matrix. For example, `rowSums` (in bgoldst's answer) will coerce your data to a matrix as an intermediate step anyways, so might as well start off with one.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a cellwise comparison against 0.75, `rowSums()`, and then a vectorized comparison against 0.5:

```
set.seed(3L); NR <- 5L; NC <- 4L; df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(NR*NC,0.75,0.1),NR));
df;
##          V1        V2        V3        V4
## 1 0.6538067 0.7530124 0.6755218 0.7192344
## 2 0.7207474 0.7585418 0.6368781 0.6546983
## 3 0.7758788 0.8616610 0.6783642 0.6851757
## 4 0.6347868 0.6281143 0.7752652 0.8724314
## 5 0.7695783 0.8767369 0.7652046 0.7699812
df[rowSums(df>0.75)/ncol(df)>=0.5,];
##          V1        V2        V3        V4
## 3 0.7758788 0.8616610 0.6783642 0.6851757
## 4 0.6347868 0.6281143 0.7752652 0.8724314
## 5 0.7695783 0.8767369 0.7652046 0.7699812
```

This can work on both matrices and data.frames.

Comment: Minor thing: could change x/n >= .5 to x >= .5*n, since the latter ought to involve fewer computations.

Comment: This is great and accomplishes the goal of the original problem

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error message because you haven't told R what columns you want to include in your subset.

You have:

```
df[your_apply_function]
```

Which doesn't specify which columns.  Instead, you should try

```
df[your_apply_function, ]
```

That means 'subset 'df' for all rows that match the result of this apply function, and all columns'.  Edit:  I don't think this will work either.

However, I would approach it by using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
rowcounts <- apply(df, 1, function(x) rowSums(x > 0.75))
df <- bind_cols(df, rowcounts)
df <- filter(df, rowcounts > ncol(df)/2)
```

I didn't get to test this yet (code still running on my machine), but it looks right to my eye.  When I get a chance I will test it.

Comment: Thank you, this was my first attempt at answering a question. :)